# User with Plone Reviewer Role is not able to see publish options when in pending state

Tags: plone

The site is using simple publication workflow
What I have tried is
1. Add the user to the role Reviewer
2. Under sharing for the folder I gave the user reviewer and view rights.
3. I even went into zope and edit the workflow and check all in the permission for reviewer role.

But under the drop down that allows the reviewer to publish, the publish option is missing. Only advance and send back option is available.

Below is the permission in pending state

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: advance? That's not a workflow transition title in the Simple Publication Workflow. It sounds like you have customized workflow.

Comment: I guess it's a typo, he means "Advanced...", which leads to the content_status_history view.

Comment: I meant Advanced. Yes I did make changes, but I am unable to determine why the publish option is not showing.

Comment: I should have figured that out on my own ;)

Comment: The transition "publish" can be protected, by roles, permissions, expression. One of those says "No". You could share a diff with the changes with us (portal_setup > snapshot)?

Comment: Here is link to the snapshot for simple pub workflow. Is this what you want? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3LNer5qL4CtTDVWb0NmbE5jZTA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a custom workflow. Your *publish* transition is protected by the `Request review` permission, which is uncommon (this is the permission for users who want to submit for publication).

Normally the "main" permission for Reviewer role is `Review portal content`.